Memory deallocation issue with parent nodes in C++ reverse-mode autodiff
I am implementing reverse-mode automatic differentiation in C++ but am encountering an issue where the memory of parent functions (variables) is getting deallocated when I create new functions that depend on multiple parents. I believe using shared pointer for managing parent relationships could solve this issue, but I’m unsure how to integrate it into my code. How can I use shared pointer correctly to prevent parent memory from being prematurely deallocated?
And this code is running when I add each function piecewise.
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
#include<functional>

using namespace std;

class Variable{
    private:
        double value;
        double grad;
        function<void()> _backward;
        vector<Variable*> _parents;
        bool visited;

    public:
        Variable(double value){
            this->value = value;
            this->grad = 0.0;
            this->_backward = [](){};
            this->visited = false;
        }

        Variable operator + (const Variable& other){
            cout<<"add"<<endl;
            Variable out(this->value + other.value);
            out._parents.push_back(this);
            out._parents.push_back(const_cast<Variable*>(&other));

            out._backward = [this, &other, &out]() {
                this->grad += out.grad;
                const_cast<Variable*>(&other)->grad += out.grad;

                cout<<"addition "<<this->grad<<"\t"<<other.grad<<endl;
            };
            return out;
        }


        
        Variable operator * (const Variable& other){
            cout<<"mul"<<endl;
            Variable out(this->value * other.value);
            out._parents.push_back(this);
            out._parents.push_back(const_cast<Variable*>(&other));

            out._backward = [this, &other, &out]() {
                this->grad += const_cast<Variable&>(other).value * out.grad;
                const_cast<Variable*>(&other)->grad += this->value * out.grad;
                cout<<this->grad<<"\t"<<other.grad<<endl;
            };
            return out;
        }


        Variable operator - (const Variable& other){
            cout<<"sub"<<endl;
            Variable out(this->value - other.value);
            out._parents.push_back(this);
            out._parents.push_back(const_cast<Variable*>(&other));

            out._backward = [this, &other, &out]() {
                cout<<this->grad<<endl;
                this->grad += out.grad;
                const_cast<Variable*>(&other)->grad -= out.grad;
                cout<<"Subtraction: "<<this->grad<<"\t"<<other.grad<<endl;

            };
            return out;
        }


        Variable operator / (const Variable& other){
            cout<<"div"<<endl;
            Variable out(this->value / other.value);
            out._parents.push_back(this);
            out._parents.push_back(const_cast<Variable*>(&other));

            out._backward = [this, &other, &out]() {
                this->grad += out.grad / other.value;
                const_cast<Variable*>(&other)->grad -= (this->value / pow(other.value, 2)) * out.grad;
                cout<<"Division: "<<this->grad<<"\t"<<other.grad<<endl;
            };
            return out;
        }


        Variable power(const Variable& other){
            cout<<"pow"<<endl;
            Variable out(pow(this->value, other.value));
            out._parents.push_back(this);
            out._parents.push_back(const_cast<Variable*>(&other));

            out._backward = [this, &other, &out]() {
                this->grad += other.value * pow(this->value, (other.value-1)) * out.grad;
                const_cast<Variable*>(&other)->grad += pow(this->value, other.value) * log(this->value) * out.grad;
            };
            return out;
        }


        Variable sine(){
            cout<<"sin"<<endl;
            Variable out(sin(this->value));
            out._parents.push_back(this);

            out._backward = [this, &out] () {
                this->grad += cos(this->value) * out.grad;
                cout<<"Sine: "<<this->grad<<endl;
            };
            return out;
        }

        Variable cosine(){
            cout<<"cos"<<endl;
            Variable out(cos(this->value));
            out._parents.push_back(this);

            out._backward = [this, &out] () {
                this->grad -= sin(this->value) * out.grad;
                cout<<"Cosine: "<<this->grad<<endl;

            };
            return out;
        }

        Variable tangent(){
            cout<<"tan"<<endl;
            Variable out(tan(this->value));
            out._parents.push_back(this);

            out._backward = [this, &out] () {
                this->grad += (1 / pow(cos(this->value), 2)) * out.grad;
                cout<<"Tangent: "<<this->grad<<endl;

            };
            return out;
        }

        Variable exponential(){
            cout<<"exp"<<endl;
            Variable out(exp(this->value));
            out._parents.push_back(this);

            out._backward = [this, &out] () {
                this->grad += exp(this->value) * out.grad;
                cout<<"Exponential: "<<this->grad<<endl;

            };
            return out;
        }
        

        void backward() {
            this->grad = 1.0;
            vector<Variable*> funcs;
            funcs.push_back(this);

            while(!funcs.empty()){
                Variable *f = funcs.back();
                funcs.pop_back();
                

                if (f->visited){
                    continue;
                }
                f->visited = true;
                if (f->_backward){
                    f->_backward();
                }
                for (Variable* parent: f->_parents){
                    
                    if (!parent->_parents.empty()){
                        funcs.push_back(parent);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }




        double getGrad(){
            return this->grad;
        }

        double getValue(){
            return this->value;
        }
};

int main(){
    Variable x(2);
    Variable y(3);
    Variable z = (x / y) - (x.tangent() * y.cosine()) + x.exponential();
    // This works.
    // Variable div_result = x / y;
    // Variable tan_result = x.tangent();
    // Variable cos_result = y.cosine();
    // Variable mul_result = tan_result * cos_result;
    // Variable sub_result = div_result - mul_result;
    // Variable exp_result = x.exponential();
    // Variable z = sub_result + exp_result;

    cout<<endl<<"Backward Pass"<<endl<<endl;
    z.backward();

    cout<<"Value of z: "<<z.getValue()<<endl;
    cout<<"Gradient with respect to x: "<<x.getGrad()<<endl;
    cout<<"Gradient with respect to y: "<<y.getGrad()<<endl;
    return 0;
}

I tried using shared pointer.

This is quite a lot of code. Looks like you can reduce it to a [mre] (for example: use only one opertor, assuming the issue of all is similar), which will help us help you.

Regarding your shared pointer question: did you try making _parents a std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Variable>> (and go on from there) ?

@wohlstad On making z = x * y, it works because the object is not temporary. However, when making _parents a shared_ptr, I need to make many other things, such as functions and f, shared_ptr as well, and I am not able to do all that.

"I am not able to do all that." Why? What's stopping you? Currently, you are busy storing pointers and capturing references to temporary objects, objects that are long gone by the time you attempt to dereference those pointers and references.

What I'd do. Have class named say VariableImpl, with a data member std::vector<std::shared_ptr<VariableImpl*>> _parents and other members similar to current Variable. This class is only ever held by shared_ptr. Do not add overloaded operators to this class. Then, Variable would have a single data member of type std::shared_ptr<VariableImpl>. It would have overloaded operators and such; the implementation of say Variable::operator+ would set up a new VariableImpl representing addition, and return a Variable wrapping a shared pointer to that VariableImpl

@IgorTandetnik Thanks, it worked.
